# Not able to update the data with @change in Vue js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am not able to populate the updated data to the child component when doing on-change from a select box with local data/object. But I am able to load data to the child component everytime when I click the submit button with the help of API. I need help to refresh my child component with my updated data when I do the on-change from the select box. Find the below code which I'm trying. That too when I do on-change first time it was updating the props in child component, but when I do the same it is not going to the child component, it stops i the parent component itself.

Component-1:

```
<template>
 <div>
 <div class="row">
  <select v-model="selectedemp" @change="filterempdata($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">Select emp/option>
      <option v-for="option in empfilterlist" v-bind:value="option.value" v-bind:key="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="compone">
  <empView v-if='loaded' :empDetails='empData'></empView>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-on:click="getEmpDetails">Fetch Data</button>
 </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
 import updatedemp from './empView'
 export default {
 name: 'cluster',
components: {
  'empView': updatedemp
},
data () {
  return {
    loaded: false,
    emptData: {},
    empfilterlist: [
        { text: 'Department', value: '1' },
        { text: 'Status', value: '2' },
    ],
    selectedemp: '',
   }
 },
 methods: {
filterempdata: function (selectedoption) {
  console.log('Onchange value - ' + selectedOption)
  Vue.set(this.empData, 'Department', selectedoption)
},
getEmpDetails: function () {
     this.$http.get('http://localhost:7070/getemmdata')
      .then((response) => {
        this.empData = response.data
        this.loaded = true
       },
       response => {
         console.log('test' + JSON.stringify(response))
       }
     )
   }
 }      
}
</script>
```

Component: 2

```
 <template>
  <div class="empView">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <h3>{{ empid }}</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    {{ empname }}
   </div>
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
  export default {
    name: 'empView',
    props: ['empDetails'],
    data () {
      return {
        empid: this.empDetails.id,
        empname: this.empDetails.name
      }
    },
    watch: {
      workflowDetails: function (changes) {
      console.log('data updated ' + JSON.stringify(changes))
      this.empid = changes.id
      this.empname = changes.name
      this.department = changes.Department
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it this line `this.empData.WorkflowFilter = selectedoption` that is not working as expected?

Comment: Yes not working

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is here:

```
filterempdata: function (selectedoption) {
  console.log(')
  this.empData.WorkflowFilter = selectedoption
  this.empData = this.empData
}
```

By default, `empData` is:

```
data () {
  return {
    loading: false,
    emptData: null,
```

So `this.empData.WorkflowFilter = selectedoption` should not work, as well as `this.empData = this.empData` does nothing.

Just make the default value an empty object and update it according to selection (just setting `WorkflowFilter`).

This should do the trick. Another weird this is the `loading` property. Your second component will be visible only if `loading = true`, which is odd. Maybe use `loaded` instead?

Comment: Thanks will change that to reloaded

Comment: I have updated my code can you help me. What's going wrong, still I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: What's in the console? Errors? What' the issue, what's the result?

Comment: It is not going to child component. Only parent component console are getting values.

Comment: Well I cannot help to things like "it's not working" :) Try, see the results, explain. Make JSFiddle with a simple demo showing what is not working, so we can test it.. This way it would be a miracle if someone helps you.

Comment: Now you're doing `this.empData = response.data` in your response from server which I bet rewrites everything....

Comment: response.data is a callback which gives the whole object as fresh for each search. But when i do the onchange i am just appending some property to the response data which I received from the API. So whenever i do onchange i am doing some change in the whole object. This changes are not reflecting. Will to try do some fiddle. I am struggling to create a fiddle.